# bruteforce on aes 256 cbc mode

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc, attack

i have a series of encrypted text , they encrypted by aes 256 bit cbc mode for every encrypted text
 there is an iv that i have them also and i know its algorithm is aes 256 bit cbc mode
 i can generate new encrypted values that i know what is plain text, but the iv would be different
i have something else named mac that i don't know what it is, it is 64 character in hex format
 by the way i know the algorithm is for one of laravel plugins named elocryptfive can i do any attack on it to find key or decrypt values?

Comment: In a security/encryption context, MAC usually means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because with the information given, it could only (and unlikely) be answered by diving into the internals of a particular (and not even well defined) piece of software, and finding a gross mistake or backdoor.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: Chances are there are no attacks against this scheme.**

What you are describing sounds exactly like a [chosen-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack), e.g. you can query an oracle to encrypt plaintexts of your choice (using the oracle's random [IVs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)).

Now, this attack is already stopped by [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)-[CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_block_chaining#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) which is provably immune to this sort of attack. And furthermore it seems like you can't even mount more advanced attacks which would work against plain AES-CBC as a *message authentication code* ([MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)) seems to be used and judging by your description it's probably [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)-[SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA256) (which gives 256 bit = 32 byte = 64 hex chars output). If these two are put together even somewhat decently (e.g. [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/23623)), then there's no chance you will learn anything about the key or any plaintexts you didn't query yourself.

That said, the implementation may have flaws (such as being vulnerable to [padding attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle) or actually not MAC'ing the data but only [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) it), may offer [side-channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_channel) (because of a bad implementation of AES) or may be otherwise exploitable (standard software exploits circumventing the encryption).